# Task<Geoposition> does not contain a definition for 'Coordinate' error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-universal

I followed the examples and documentations available and still getting this error. I also tried the potential fix and it didn't help either. I'm following this code from MVA.

Code:

LocationManager.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;
namespace WeatherNow
{
    public class LocationManager
    {
        public async static Task<Geoposition> GetPosition()
        {
            var accessStatus=await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
            if (accessStatus != GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed)
                throw new Exception();
            Geolocator geolocater = new Geolocator { DesiredAccuracyInMeters= 0               };
     Geoposition position = await geolocater.GetGeopositionAsync();
       return position;
        }
    }
}
```

Mainpage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace WeatherNow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {


        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }


        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var position = LocationManager.GetPosition();
            RootObject myWeather = await OpenWeatherMapProxy.GetWeather(position.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude, position.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude);
            string Icon = String.Format("ms-appx:///Assets/Weather/{0}.png", myWeather.weather[0].icon);
            ResultTextBlock.Text = myWeather.name + " - " + ((int)myWeather.main.temp).ToString() + " - " + myWeather.weather[0].description;
            ResultImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Icon, UriKind.Absolute));

        }
    }
}
```

OpenWeatherProxy.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WeatherNow
{
    public class OpenWeatherMapProxy
    {

        public async static Task<RootObject> GetWeather(double lat,double lon)
        {
            var http = new HttpClient();
            var response = await http.GetAsync("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98");
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

            var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
            var data = (RootObject)serializer.ReadObject(ms);

            return data;

        }


    }


    [DataContract]
    public class Coord
    {
        [DataMember]
        public double lon { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public double lat { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Weather
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string main { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string description { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string icon { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Main
    {
        [DataMember]
        public double temp { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public double pressure { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int humidity { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public double temp_min { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public double temp_max { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public double sea_level { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public double grnd_level { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Wind
    {
        [DataMember]
        public double speed { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public double deg { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Clouds
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int all { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Sys
    {
        [DataMember]
        public double message { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string country { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int sunrise { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int sunset { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class RootObject
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Coord coord { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string @base { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Main main { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Wind wind { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int dt { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Sys sys { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int cod { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: @SonerGönül ok, updating

Answer (score 2):

This is an async method:

```
LocationManager.GetPosition();
```

So it's returning a `Task<GeoPosition>` instead of just a `GeoPosition`.  Which, as the error says, doesn't contain a `Coordinate` property.  If you want to get the *result* of that task (the `GeoPosition` object produced by the task), await it:

```
var position = await LocationManager.GetPosition();
```

Comment: thanks! that was it. Can't believe I missed that all this time.